# How to get Ckan API access statistics?

Tags: ckan

I would like to know if there is a way to get `Ckan` API access statistics ?
I tried the `Ckan Page View Tracking` but it seems to be only for graphic interface.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: Do you need stats about API access or stats about datasets reviews, number of datasets etc?

Comment: @TobySpeight Hello. Thank you for your comment. But there is no code. I just would like to know if there is for example a file containing the statistics of use of the Ckan API.

Comment: @ZoranPandovski Thanks for reply. What I need is statistics for accessing through API a dataset or resource.

Comment: It sounds like it's not a programming question then - usage questions have their own Stack Exchange sites, such as [su] and [sf].

Comment: @TobySpeight Ok I'm going to ask my question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record API use using the [ckanext-googleanalytics](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-googleanalytics) CKAN extension, which intercepts the API controller and sends Google Analytics the events. The PR which introduces this feature is here: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-googleanalytics/pull/6/files

That records calls to the CKAN API, such as access to the dataset and resource metadata. You may want to extend it to include the Datastore accesses of the dataset/resource data itself. And part of CKAN can be instrumented in a similar way.

NB I believe this will need some work to make it work with CKAN 2.7.x and later, because it targets CKAN's API when it was a Pylons controller (i.e. pre 2.7.x) and was [rewritten](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3239) to be a Flask view, so the interception of the calls will need to be different.

Comment: I'm coming back to you to confirm that `ckanext-googleanalytics` work perfectly for API analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you need statistics about your site e.g top tags, datasets revision, number of datasets etc you can use Stats extension. For more information check docs http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/stats.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i tried and its only for graphic interface access.

Comment: If that doesn't fit your needs, check ckanext-googleanalytics from D Read answer